# How to import pages into WordPress?

Tags: wordpress.com

[From [ed.talmadge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3248484/how-to-impot-pages-into-wordpress-closed)]

I have a site that would like to migrate to WordPress. My current site contains about 1,000 pages that contain just information. No blog articles, ecommerce or anything fancy.

I am aware that WordPress allows the importing of pages. All the tutorials I can find deal with migrating an existing blog (example, Blogger) to WordPress.

I would like to create some type of feed (.xml, RSS, .csv, or whatever...) from my existing site and import that into WordPress. I would like all my current pages to be "WordPress Pages" (not posts).

What feed format and content do I use to ensure that the proper page titles, descriptions, permalinks, category associations, etc get correctly transferred to WordPress?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Import HTML Pages plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/import-html-pages/) might help you. If you haven't installed WordPress yet, you might want to start with WordPress 2.9.2 (the current maximum version tested with the plugin) and then update to 3.0.1 once you've completed the import.

Potentially the plugin could have problems with HTML that isn't well-formed, but you can use [HTML Tidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/) and/or the [W3C Validator service](http://validator.w3.org/) to help check and clean up your pages before you import them.